# How to extract data from cookie using angular ngCookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have cookie data printed in console now i want to create object that will get data from cookie firstname ,lastname,eamil and id. How i can create object when i recieve data in below format ?

mainCtrl.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
  .controller('AccessCtrl',['$scope', '$cookies','UserAccessFactory',
    function ($scope, $cookies,UserAccessFactory) {
      $scope.newUser = {};
      $scope.patternAttuid = new RegExp("^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-z0-9]$");
      $scope.cookie = $cookies.get('attESHr');
      console.log('newUser',$scope.cookie)

    });
```

data printed $scope.cookie

`newUser Mike|Pierro|mp529u@us.att.com|||sl3561||mp529u,RHCRSMK,SBGPQX9,4131585|NNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNNYNNNNNN|MIKE|EY1PE2600`|

Comment: Who creates the cookie? Do you have to parse that format?

Comment: Yes i have to parse the format.

Comment: Well then apply something using split? You have to know that the values cant have the separator char.. Also, this has nothing to do with angular, right? You just want to parse a value

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to split cookie based on my data if i use split its adding data to array but i want to separate firstname and lastname etc values for new object `newUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to get the values separated. You should know that doing this is not encouraged because if the format changes, your code will be broken. But if you really need to parse that string, you could try this:

```
var parts = $scope.cookie.split("|"); 
$scope.newUser.firstName = parts[0];
$scope.newUser.lastName = parts[1];
$scope.newUser.email = parts[2];
// ... etc with all the other values, keeping in mind the index
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me it worked just one last thing i am stuck how i can get `mp529u` value from data.

Comment: You will have to split the value of the 7th index by `,` .Right?

Comment: from 7th index i just need first value that is id `mp529u`

Comment: Thank you i got it!